# How to use Moment.JS to check whether the current time is between 2 times

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Say the current time is `09:34:00` (`hh:mm:ss`), and I have two other times in two variables:

```
var beforeTime = '08:34:00',
    afterTime = '10:34:00';
```

How do I use Moment.JS to check whether the current time is between `beforeTime` and `afterTime`?

I've seen [`isBetween()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/), and I've tried to use it like:

```
moment().format('hh:mm:ss').isBetween('08:27:00', '10:27:00')
```

but that doesn't work because as soon as I format the first (current time) moment into a string, it's no longer a moment object. I've also tried using:

```
moment('10:34:00', 'hh:mm:ss').isAfter(moment().format('hh:mm:ss')) && moment('08:34:00', 'hh:mm:ss').isBefore(moment().format('hh:mm:ss'))
```

but I get `false`, because again when I format the current time, it's no longer a moment.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620498/comparing-two-times-with-moment-js

Answer (score 142, accepted):

- You can pass moment instances to `isBetween()`
- leave out the `format()` calls, what you want is to pass parse formats like int the first moment() of your second attempt.

That's all:

```
const format = 'hh:mm:ss';

// var time = moment() gives you current time. no format required.
const time = moment('09:34:00', format);
const beforeTime = moment('08:34:00', format);
const afterTime = moment('10:34:00', format);

if (time.isBetween(beforeTime, afterTime)) {
  console.log('is between');
} else {
  console.log('is not between');
}
// prints 'is between'
```

Comment: This seems great! +1 but how would I format the current time as 'hh:mm:ss' without using .format()? So, instead of hardcoding the current `time`, could I get it via moment?

Comment: Basically a way to do something like: `moment('hh:mm:ss')` without actually giving the time, because I want moment to give me that...

Comment: Ah, in that case just do `moment()`. you don't have to specify an input format if you don't input a time string. Later, when you would like to actually print out the date in the HTML for the user, you want to give moment an *output* format, so then you use `.format('hh:mm:ss')`, but that is the very last step. For everything in between (calculations, comparisons etc. ) a format is not needed.

Comment: Ahhhh! I see! I was overcomplicating it quite a bit! :/ Thanks a lot! :D it works now :)

Comment: The confusing bit I think is why the author is using hh:mm:ss and not HH:mm:ss as hh:mm:ss is in 12 hour format which does not make sense to me without specifying am and pm.

Comment: it doesn't work for the following instance:   var time = moment('21:34:00',format),
    beforeTime = moment('20:34:00', format),
    afterTime = moment('01:34:00', format); If it works, please let me know.

Comment: it doesn't work because your `afterTime` is before your `beforeTime`: 01:34 is before 20:34. You of course want 01:34 *on the next day*, but you didn't define that. So simply do `moment('01:34:00', format).add(1, 'day')`

Answer (score 5):

I had to use `isBetween` and `isSame` in my case to cover the `before` and `after` time I used in the isBetween condition.

```
function getTimeCategory(time) {
  let timeCategory = '';
  const timeFormat = 'HH:mm:ss';

  if (
    time.isBetween(moment('00:00:00', timeFormat), moment('04:59:59', timeFormat)) ||
    time.isSame(moment('00:00:00', timeFormat)) ||
    time.isSame(moment('04:59:59', timeFormat))
  ) {
    timeCategory = 'DAWN';
  } else if (
    time.isBetween(moment('05:00:00', timeFormat), moment('11:59:59', timeFormat)) ||
    time.isSame(moment('05:00:00', timeFormat)) ||
    time.isSame(moment('11:59:59', timeFormat))
  ) {
    timeCategory = 'MORNING';
  } else if (
    time.isBetween(moment('12:00:00', timeFormat), moment('16:59:59', timeFormat)) ||
    time.isSame(moment('12:00:00', timeFormat)) ||
    time.isSame(moment('16:59:59', timeFormat))
  ) {
    timeCategory = 'NOON';
  } else if (
    time.isBetween(moment('17:00:00', timeFormat), moment('23:59:59', timeFormat)) ||
    time.isSame(moment('17:00:00', timeFormat)) ||
    time.isSame(moment('23:59:59', timeFormat))
  ) {
    timeCategory = 'NIGHT';
  }

  return timeCategory;
}
```

Comment: it's easier to use `moment().format("a")` to get the time category. But I know what you wrote above is just an example of the answer to the question.

Comment: From the docs: "Version 2.13.0 introduces inclusivity. A [ indicates inclusion of a value. A ( indicates exclusion. If the inclusivity parameter is used, both indicators must be passed." So you can eliminate the `isSame` by using `isBetween(first, second, null, '[]');`

Answer (score 2):

I have use moment function combination isSameOrAfter and isSameOrBefore instead of isBetween.

```
if(moment(currentTime,'HH:mm:ss').isSameOrAfter(moment(shift_dayFrom,'HH:mm:ss')) && 
moment(currentTime,'HH:mm:ss').isSameOrAfter(moment(shift_dayTo,'HH:mm:ss')))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    const beforeTime = moment(t, "HH:mm");
    const afterTime = moment(t2, "HH:mm");
    
    
             
                
   const time = moment(dueTime, "HH:mm");
    
   if(time.isSameOrAfter(beforeTime) && time.isSameOrBefore(afterTime))
                {
                  
                }
```

Answer (score -3):

The example on that page is

```
moment('2010-10-20').isBetween('2010-10-19', '2010-10-25'); // true
```

there's no call to `format` function as in your code so I suggest to try

```
moment('09:34:00').isBetween('08:34:00', '10:34:00');
```

Comment: He should be passing a parse format string as the second argument (see my answer), otherwise moment will raise a deprecation warning.