# How to limit time using moment javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

the problem is it still executing the code inside if statement even if the input for timegraveyard is 8:00 AM

```
var timeGraveyard = moment(itemT.ScreeningStart, 'LT');
var startTimeGraveyard = moment('12:00 PM', 'LT');
var endtimeGraveyard = moment('6:00 PM', 'LT');
if (timeGraveyard.isBetween(startTimeGraveyard, endtimeGraveyard)) {
   $('#lblGraveyard').text("Graveyard Schedule");
}
```

Comment: This looks like it should work. Are you sure that `itemT.screeningStart` has the value you think it does? Or possibly `#lblGraveyard` isn't the correct identifier?

Comment: Yeah itemT.screeningStart has a value i've checked it in chrome DevTools

Comment: Works as expected for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/vfd8o95q/5/

Comment: I think the problem lies with the `itemT.ScreeningStart`, hardcoded time value seems to be working as expected. Check this answer for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36197219/6138595

Comment: Yes I've changed it and it work out. btw itemT.ScreeningStart came from Web API Thanks guys :)