# Time input passed time validation with moment

Tags: javascript

Hi I have input type time, how is it possible to validate, not let user type time that has passed, or show validation saying you cannot add time that has passeed
with moment js

```html
<input type="time" value />
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197031/how-to-use-moment-js-to-check-whether-the-current-time-is-between-2-times