# Checking if time is between two times where the hours are different

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if a time falls between two times but the second time is in the next hour and the minutes are smaller than the first minutes.

For example (This works perfectly)

```js
const time = new Date();
// if time is between 8:15 and 8:55
if (time.getHours() == 8 && time.getMinutes() >= 15 && time.getMinutes() < 55) {
}
```

Because there minutes can be a number between 15 and 55
However here (Time between 8:55 and 9:35)

```js
if (time.getHours() == 8 && time.getMinutes() >= 55 && time.getMinutes() < 35) {
                    
}
```

This will not work as wanted because 35 is smaller than 55 and "minutes" the number cannot both be above 55 and below 35.

If anyone can help me, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/36197219/5871092

Comment: @Madhav your linked answer is about momentjs. For new projects you should consider using alternatives to that library.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `hh:mm` into `minutes` and check if it is in between two time or not

```js
function convertTimeToMinutes(time) {
    const [, hh, mm] = time.match(/(\d{2}):(\d{2})/);
    const minutes = parseInt(hh, 10) * 60 + parseInt(mm, 10);
    return minutes;
}

const firstTime = convertTimeToMinutes('08:15');
const secondTime = convertTimeToMinutes('08:55');

const checkTime1 = '08:20';
const checkTime2 = '08:56';

const firstCheckTime = convertTimeToMinutes(checkTime1);
const secondCheckTime = convertTimeToMinutes(checkTime2);

console.log(firstCheckTime > firstTime && firstCheckTime < secondTime);   // true
console.log(secondCheckTime > firstTime && secondCheckTime < secondTime); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to compare times and dates with vanilla js is like reinventing the wheel. These operations are pretty standard and there are libraries which already have methods  for the same.

The library moment js can be recommended   for this purpose. Use the isBetween method of the moment object.

```
 moment('2010-10-20').isBetween('2010-10-19', '2010-10-25'); // true
```

Comment: For new projects you should consider an other library then momentjs.