# MomentJS: detect time difference in terms of minute

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i tried this but not getting expected result.

first i diff date the below way and it works

```
var inputDate = moment('02/10/2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY');
var birthday = moment('02/05/2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY');
var diff = inputDate.diff(birthday, 'days'); 
alert(diff);
```

but when i follow the same approach for time diff then fail.

```
var beginningTime = moment('08:45:21');
var endTime = moment('07:00:01');
var difftm= beginningTime.diff(endTime, 'mm'); 
alert(difftm);
```

i need difference in terns of time. where i made the mistake? please let me know. thanks

Comment: What is `mm` supposed to mean? Above you use `days`, doesn't it work if you write `minutes` ?

Comment: no minute does not work....see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/447sxg27/

Comment: It works: https://jsfiddle.net/447sxg27/1/

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/ isBefore isAfter etc like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620498/comparing-two-times-with-moment-js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moment can handle times without dates as long as you tell the parser that is what you are looking for.
Please keep in mind when you parse times without dates that any diff calculations that you make may not account for DST transitions, and thus may be wrong.
When you are working with times that do not have dates, I recommend using UTC mode so that you don't accidentally end up making a calculation over a DST transition that ends up being wrong. As such, your code can be written as follows:

```js
console.log(moment.utc('08:45:21', 'HH:mm:ss')
  .diff(moment.utc('07:00:01', 'HH:mm:ss'), 'minutes'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

It is, I suppose, minutely possible that you would encounter a scenario where the first call to moment.utc evaluated in a different utc day than the second call, and caused an inaccurate calculation. For this reason you may want to specify a date instead of just parsing time.

In either case, use UTC mode to avoid any possible DST complications.

Comment: thanks for your code. without utc can not we diff time with moment. if possible would post the code.

Comment: I didn't down vote your post, so I can't remove it. As far as your first question, I don't know why you mean by diff without UTC. You certainly can diff in local mode, but if a DST transition happens between your start time and your end time, you will get the wrong result. With UTC mode, you are assured that any two times are exactly the same distance apart in any browser.

Answer (score 3):

If you give your second example a date - a non-sensical one if necessary - then you'll get the difference in milliseconds.

```
var beginningTime = moment('1900-01-01 08:45:21');
var endTime = moment('1900-01-01 07:00:01');
var difftm = beginningTime.diff(endTime, 'mm');
alert(difftm);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nicholasduffy/cz2xbjvw/

Comment: i have two time stored in two variable without date part....then how could i diff them with moment to get difference in respect of time? is it possible without date part?

Comment: Just tack on a date, like: beginningTime = '1900-01-01 ' + beginningTime; Use the same date for both, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `minutes` instead of `days` :

```
var beginningTime = moment('1900-01-01 08:45:21');
var endTime = moment('1900-01-01 07:00:01');
var difftm= beginningTime.diff(endTime, 'minutes'); 
alert(difftm);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/447sxg27/1/

As duffn mentioned in his answer, your dates have to be valid dates (date + time).

Comment: Moment can parse times if you configure it to do so. No need for the dates.