# moment.js compare times with no dates

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

Is there an easy way in moment.js to compare times with no date attached?
It works when I have a full ISO object with date+time, but not when it's only a time.

For example, this basic code doesn't work because, I presume, it expects a date in the value:

```
var time_obj = moment(active_time_format, "HH:mm:ss");
console.log(time_obj.isBefore('12:00:00'));
```

I understand that I can just add an arbitrary date in there, but what is the elegant way to do this?

Update:

This works from the comment below by @RichardHamilton:

```
var time_obj = moment(active_time_format, "HH:mm:ss");
console.log(time_obj.isBefore( moment('12:00:00', "HH:mm:ss") ));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two times with Moment JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620498/comparing-two-times-with-moment-js)

Comment: What is active_time_format?

Comment: For example "14:00:00"

Comment: @RichardHamilton the problem is the `.isBefore('12:00:00')` because `12:00:00` is not a date but contains only the time part. Because of that the OP has use `isBefore ( moment('12:00:00', "HH:mm:ss") );` there.

Comment: Be careful with the logic of this.  Is 12:00 am before or after 12:00 pm?  If you're truly not considering date, then *either* are possible.  If you're fixing it to a single calendar date, then it's answerable, but otherwise you have to model time as a circle (like a clock), not a line.  Consider also times near midnight.  Most people would say 12:01 am is two minutes after 11:59 pm.  It would be strange to say 11:59 pm is 23hrs 59min after 12:01 am, but that's how it is if you fix to a single date.  On a circle - BOTH are valid.

Comment: I see how not having a date makes things confusing. I assume that is why I've seen code that uses an arbitrary old date for such cases, such as 01-01-1820.