# Comparing 2 dates with momentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to compare a DAY/TIME e.g. Monday 09:00:00 with the current time to see if I am past that point in the week. e.g. If it is now 05:00:00 on Monday it should return true however it is returning false everytime

```
var dayTime = Moment("Wednesday 17:00:00", "dddd HH:mm:ss");
var now = Moment(Moment.now(), "dddd HH:mm:ss");
console.log(Moment.utc(dayTime).isBefore(now)); //returns false all the time
```

I found the following similar questions but it didn't seem to fix the issue after formatting the time.

[Comparing two times with Moment JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620498/comparing-two-times-with-moment-js)

When I replace the `moment.now()` with a string such as "Wednesday 17:00:00" it returns the expected result.

Any idea what I need to do to `moment.now()` in order for this to work correctly?

Comment: I would not expect `moment(moment.now(), "dddd HH:mm:ss")` to produce the Moment you want; `moment.now()` return an epoch time representation, and you're passing in an entirely different format string. Try just `moment(moment.now())`

Comment: moment.now shouldn't be used at all. It is an extension point that is not part of the public api. to get the current time just call moment()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, the code I posted in my question was changing the day/hour but was setting the year to 2015 which meant that it was always in the past.

To fix I separated out the Day and the Hour and set to moment. Then compared that with now. e.g.

```
moment().set({"Day": "Friday", "Hour": "17"}).isBefore(moment())
```

Answer (score 9):

Moment.now can be used as an extension point, but it's really not a public API. To get the current time in momentjs you just call `moment()`. Note that all moment calls use lowercase `moment`.

To see if your date and time is before the current time, you would just call:

```
moment('01/01/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY').isBefore(moment())
```

You would replace the date and format in question with your own.

I see that you have a date format that includes only day of week and time. Moment will parse this, but be aware that the behavior might not be what you expect. When I parse your date, I get Wednesday December 30, 2015. Exactly what day this lands on will vary by locale. In any case, I doubt that it is what you want. If at all possible, I would get year, month, and day.

If you would like to instead set the moment to Wednesday this week, set the day on the moment using `.day()`. For instance:

```
moment().day(3).format()
"2016-06-15T20:19:55-05:00"
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it doesn't quite answer my problem. I have a day/time (no year) and would like to find out if right now i am before or after that point  in a week, after looking further (and your comment) it appears that it is returning false due to the day/hour always being given a year in the past - any idea how to get over this?