# html time validation to return an error message if a time before the current time is inputted

Tags: javascript, html, validation, time

This is my html part for time- `<input   type=time name=DPTime required id=time>`

This is the java script function for the time

```
function checkTime(){
                       var check=document.getElementById(time);

                   }
```

I do not understand how to access the input time variables in order to write the checkTime function to retun an error message if the input time given is before the current time ! please help me ive been thinking about this for the whole day but is unable to develop a successful algorithm for the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `value` of the element

`document.getElementById('time').value`  will contain a string of the time value.  You can then parse that time (I recommend using moment.js) and check it.

Here's a codepen with a better example

http://codepen.io/kognate/pen/dpoPaB

Comment: i need to get an error message if the time entered is before the inputted 1 :(

Comment: Ok,  you can code that in your checking function.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620498/comparing-two-times-with-moment-js