# Javascript : How to check if a time ("09:30") is in between two times - 08:00 and 00:30

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a time (just time) is between two times - 8 Am and 12:30 pm, but I only have them in this format : 08:00 and 00:30

Comment: I think the below solution will resolve you problem and if this helps you please mask it as answer so that it can help others also

Answer (score 0):

split time string by ':' then compare the array elements or use momentjs

[Comparing two times with Moment JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620498/comparing-two-times-with-moment-js)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple function like this to convert your time to a number of minutes since 0:00

```
function getMinutes(str) {
    var time = str.split(':');
    return time[0]*60+time[1]*1;
}
```

And a similar function to get the current time into the same form in order to compare:

```
function getMinutesNow() {
    var timeNow = new Date();
    return timeNow.getHours()*60+timeNow.getMinutes();
}
```

Then convert both opening and closing time and, if it happens that closing time is before opening time, add 24 hours to it.

```
var now = getMinutesNow();
var start = getMinutes('10:00');
var end = getMinutes('2:00');
if (start > end) end += getMinutes('24:00');

if ((now > start) && (now < end))
{ // your code here
}
```

Comment: `      var now = getMinutes("00:29");
        var start = getMinutes("08:00");
        var end = getMinutes("00:30");
        if (start > end) end += getMinutes('24:00');

        if ((now > start) && (now < end))
        { // your code here
          console.log("yes");
        }`

**doesn't work**