# How to check if current time is between certain business hours?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The code below is what I'd like to ultimately end up with, but I don't think that's how momentjs works.

```
let time = moment()
let dayOfWeek = time.weekday()
let hour = time.hour()
let minutes = time.minutes()

let isBusinessHours = false

// Sunday=1, Monday=2, etc..
// Mon-Thu - 8:30am to 7:30pm

if (dayOfWeek >= 2 && dayOfWeek <= 5) {
  if ((hour >= 8 && hour <= 19) && (minutes >= 0 && minutes <= 30)) {
    isBusinessHours = true
  }
} else if (dayOfWeek == 6) { // Fri - 8:30am - 5:30pm

} else if (dayOfWeek == 7) { // Sat - 10:30am - 4:00pm

}
```

This seems like a solved issue, but I can't seem to crack it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you can do this with MomentJS.

```
let currentTime = moment()
let opening = moment('9:30am', 'h:mma')
let closing = moment('7:30pm', 'h:mma')

if (currentTime.isAfter(opening) && currentTime.isBefore(closing)) {
  console.log("It's business time!")
}
```

Comment: there is a function called `isBetween`
so you can also use `currentTime.isBetween(opening, closing)`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sunday=1, Monday=2, etc..
// Mon-Thu - 8:30am to 7:30pm

if (dayOfWeek >= 2 && dayOfWeek <= 5) {
  if ((hour >= 8 && hour <= 19) && (minutes >= 0 && minutes <= 30)) {
    isBusinessHours = true
  }
```

This code will count times between 8:00am and 8:30am as being within business hours, because hour=8, minutes>=0 and minutes<=30.

One option would be to set a beginning and ending time for Monday-Thursday, Friday, and Saturday in each of your if blocks and to use the isBefore() and isAfter() methods of MomentJS to see if the current time is within the range of the work day.

See: [Comparing two times with Moment JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620498/comparing-two-times-with-moment-js)
and: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/