# Check if time is between two values with hours and minutes in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I need to check if a time is between a start and end time.  All times are on the same day, so date is not important.  I'm able to compare hours, but I'm unsure how to add in minutes to the start and end times.

```
var thedate = new Date(); 
var dayofweek = thedate.getUTCDay(); 
var hourofday = thedate.getUTCHours(); 
var minutesofday = date.getMinutes();
function inTime() { if (dayofweek != 0 && dayofweek != 7 && (hourofday > 13 && hourofday < 20)) { return true; } return false; }
```

If I want to check whether the time is between 13:05 and 19:57, how would I add the minutes to my inTime function?  If I add them to the if statement, it fails to work:

```
 function inTime() { if (dayofweek != 0 && dayofweek != 7 && ((hourofday > 13 && minutesofday > 5) && (hourofday < 20 && minutesofday < 57))) { return true; } return false; }
```

Comment: I recommend you checkout momentjs library https://momentjs.com/. It has method to check time. Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620498/comparing-two-times-with-moment-js

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking, are you trying to figure out whether the time "now" is between two times of day?

Comment: Really? The downvoter should rethink why he is on this site. #SOreadyToHelp !

Comment: it's an X/Y problem, and if you instead solve for X, surely it's a duplicate of one of the dozen "Check if date is between two dates" questions.

Comment: I really hate answers that say "It's an X/Y problem."  No, it's a stated problem showing that I attempted to solve it before asking for help.  How are people supposed to show what they've done if they don't want comments like this?  And I checked for duplicates, but none included the issue with minutes in javascript.  I found solutions in PHP, but that doesn't necessary work in javascript.

Comment: @kevin everything is somehow slightly related to one of more than the millions of questions that exists on the internet. However its (sometimes) hard to find them, and the askers might not have the same knowledge or skill like you, so they might not be able to adapt the answers to their usecase. If there would be a real dupe, wheres your dupe vote?!

Comment: @Alligator "minutes" is the x/y problem. When dealing with date objects, they have minutes. If you compare two dates, you're comparing minutes too. so all you needed to do was create date objects for start date, end date, and the date you are comparing, then check of the latter is between the two former which is just a simple number comparison. Instead you were trying to individually compare time/date parts. x/y.

Comment: @kevin but you would need to set the `start` and `end` date to todays date ... which is slightly longer then the answers proposed below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If its `14:04` your condition will fail as `4` is smaller `5`. The simplest would probably be to just take the full minutes of the day:

```
 const start = 13 * 60 + 5;
 const end =  19 * 60 + 57;
 const date = new Date(); 
 const now = date.getHours() * 60 + date.getMinutes();

 if(start <= now && now <= end)
   alert("in time");
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was concerned about.  Excellent answer.

Comment: @alligator glad to help :)

Comment: Suggest using, or not using, the UTC methods consistently, rather than mix-and-match. :-)

Comment: Apparently two people decided to downvote *every* answer (a third downvoted one of them). **sigh**

Comment: what if the end is smaller than the start? like from 22 to 03 in the morning?

Answer (score 5):

If you're saying you want to check if the time "now" is between two times, you can express those times as minutes-since-midnight (`hours * 60 + minutes`), and the check is quite straightforward.

For instance, is it between 8:30 a.m. (inclusive) and 5:00 p.m. (exclusive):

```js
var start =  8 * 60 + 30;
var end   = 17 * 60 + 0;

function inTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  var time = now.getHours() * 60 + now.getMinutes();
  return time >= start && time < end;
}

console.log(inTime());
```

The above uses local time; if you want to check UTC instead, just use the equivalent UTC methods.

Comment: If the end date is in the following day, you just need to add 1440 mins to that time. 
if (end < start) end += 1440;

Answer (score 2):

Convert times to milliseconds and then you can compare easily.

short version:

```
if(timeToCheck.getTime() >= startTime.getTime() &&
        timeToCheck.getTime() <= endTime.getTime()) {
    // ...
}
```

OR:

```
let startTimeMilli = startTime.getTime();
let endTimeMilli = endTime.getTime();
let timeToCheckMilli = timeToCheck.getTime();

// change >= to > or <= to < as you need
if (timeToCheckMilli >= startTimeMilli && timeToCheckMilli <= endTimeMilli) {
    // do your things
}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but does that work once, or can I use that to check every single day?  For example, if I count up from 1970, I can only compare values within one day - or am I missing something?

Comment: check answer again

Comment: why are people voting down?

Comment: I upvoted not because your answer is right or well written, but because its definetly not worth three downvotes.

Comment: Alligator, I did not understand what you are asking. using milliseconds, you don't need to worry about date part. It will work even if start and end times fall on different dates.

Comment: I had downvoted because u had no code at that time. Ofc changed now.