# Check If a given time(Only hours:minutes) lies betwenn two other different time?

Tags: javascript, time

I have 2 different times:
var shiftStartTime = "05:48";
var shiftEndTime = "14:29";

And i have another time which is **selectedDate** ="06:20"(this will change according datetimepicker selection), and i want to check if **selectedDate** should be between (**shiftStartTime**  and **shiftEndTime** ).

Can anyone help in this?

Updated Code:
i have 6 different timespan like below

```
var shift1StartTime = "05:48";
var shift1EndTime = "14:18";
var shift2StartTime = "14:30";
var shift2EndTime = "22:29";
va

r shift3StartTime = "22:30";
    var shift3EndTime = "05:47";
```

using all 6 timespan i want to check the if the given time is between (shift1StartTime and shift1EndTime) return shift1

Or

if the given time is between (shift2StartTime and shift2EndTime) return shift2

Or

if the given time is between (shift3StartTime and shift3EndTime) return shift3

Comment: So you got these times as strings?

Comment: if you write your times with this format, in 24h : "HH:mm", simple string comparison would work fine. `if (shiftStartTime < selectedDate && selectedDate < shiftEndTime) console.log("ok")`. If you use actual javascript "Date" type, that would work as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if time is between two values with hours and minutes in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655310/check-if-time-is-between-two-values-with-hours-and-minutes-in-javascript)

Comment: i don't want to compare with with date. without date is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Simply compare the strings like

```
var shiftStartTime = "05:48"; var shiftEndTime = "14:29";

shiftStartTime > shiftEndTime // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some JS that does this, although better formatted time would make it a lot easier

```
function findTotalTime(time) {
  hours = parseInt(time.substring(0,2))
  mins = parseInt(time.substring(3,5))
  return (hours*60) + mins
}

startTime = findTotalTime(shiftStartTime)
endTime = findTotalTime(shiftEndTime)
selectedTime = findTotalTime(selectedDate)
if (selectedTime > startTime && selectedTime < endTime) {
  // time is inbetween shifts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const date  = new Date();
const shiftStartTime = '05:48';
const shiftEndTime = '14:29';
const selectedDate = '14:20';
const start = date.setHours(+shiftStartTime.split(':')[0], +shiftStartTime.split(':')[1], 0, 0);
const end = date.setHours(+shiftEndTime.split(':')[0], +shiftEndTime.split(':')[1], 0, 0);
const selected = date.setHours(+selectedDate.split(':')[0], +selectedDate.split(':')[1], 0, 0);
if (start < selected && selected < end) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so you got three relative times as strings in the format `HH:mm`. I'm assuming that your times are given as 24h strings / military time, because otherwise, you'd need an A.M. / P.M. specifier.

It is always useful to have the data you are working with in a well-suited machine-readable format, so you could parse them into a simple object holding the hour and minute as numbers.

A function doing this could look like this.

```js
function parseTimeStr(time) {
    // The pattern of your input,
    // allows spaces around the `:`
    // and single-digit inputs like `8:00`
    let re = /([0-9][0-9]?)\s*:\s*([0-9][0-9]?)/;
    let result = re.exec(time.trim());

    if (result === null) {
        throw "No match"
    }

    let hour = parseInt(result[1], 10);
    let minute = parseInt(result[2], 10);

    /* handle out of range values here */

    return { hour, minute };
}
```

Alright, so you have these objects now. How do you compare them? [There's a pattern for that:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Parameters) Have a function returning whether the first argument is greater (1), equal (0), or less (-1) than the second.

Writing this is simple now that the time is an object:

```js
function cmpDate(date1, date2) {
    if (date1.hour > date2.hour) {
        return 1;
    } else if (date1.hour < date2.hour) {
        return -1;
    } else if (date1.minute > date2.minute) {
        return 1;
    } else if (date1.minute < date2.minute) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Alright, now we can have a helper function checking if the first argument is in the closed interval defined by the last two arguments:

```js
function isInShift(time, shiftStart, shiftEnd) {
    // time is greater or equal shiftStart
    // and less or equal shiftEnd
    return cmpDate(time, shiftStart) !== -1 && cmpDate(time, shiftEnd) !== 1;
}
```

You can then finally make your comparison by calling `isInShift(parseTimeStr(selectedTime), parseTimeStr(shiftStartTime), parseTimeStr(shiftEndTime))`. This will return a boolean. You can easily extend this infrastructure for multiple shifts.

Be aware that both reality and your users can be more ... screwy than you'd expect.
The above code does not do error handling for invalid time inputs, neither does it account for overnight shifts, but these are details that you can easily work out, you just have to put some effort into thinking of them.