# Moment JS compare hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm mapping through array that has data like:
`['00:00', '00:30', '01:00']` and all way long to 23:30.

Each of array element is to be compared with the time of Open and Close times, which are like open '00:15', close '22:00' etc.

According to comparison I need to disable or enable elements on page: if open and close in range - elements are available, otherwise - disabled. 
So the question is how to compare these hours and minutes via moment JS?

Comment: Covert the string to date and then make comparison. `moment('00:30', 'HH:mm')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two times with Moment JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620498/comparing-two-times-with-moment-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moment makes this fairly simple:

```js
var times = ['00:00', '00:30', '01:00']

var parseTime = timeString => moment(timeString, 'HH:mm')

var closingTime = parseTime('00:00')

var pastClosing = times.map(time => parseTime(time).isAfter(closingTime));

console.dir(pastClosing)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/locale/en-gb.js"></script>
```

Comment: seems like I didnt parse my array element before comparing... you pushed me on the right solution, thanks, mate!