# Compare time in an array to verify if it is incremented by 2 hours

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have an array of strings that are in time format example '6pm' or '5am'. I want to verify that the elements in the array are incremented by 2 hours. I first used .replace to remove the pm and am and get the difference between the first and next element to see if it's 2, but had a problem with the time between '12am', '2am' and '12pm', '2pm'. So I thought of converting it to 24 hours or minutes but still get the same issue. I am not sure how should I convert it to compare if the elements are incremented by 2 hours or if there is a library that compares by date. Here is what I have:

```
const exampleArr = ['6pm', '8pm', '10pm', '12am', '2am', '4am', '6am', '8am', '10am', '12pm'];
const modifiedTempArr = [];

for(let i = 0; i < exampleArr.length; i++) {
  let temp = exampleArr[i].replace('pm', '').replace('am', '');
  //console.log(temp);
  let timeInMin = temp * 60;
  console.log(timeInMin);
  modifiedTempArr.push(timeInMin);
}

// or
for(let i = 0; i < exampleArr.length; i++) {
  var momentObj = moment(exampleArr[i], ["hA"]);
  console.log(momentObj.format("HH:mm")); 
}

// also tried this
var d1 = new Date(parseInt(exampleArr[3])); // 12am
var d2 = new Date(parseInt(exampleArr[4])); // 2am
let timeDifference = Math.abs(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());
console.log(timeDifference); // got 10
```

Comment: "or if there is a library that compares by date". In JavaScript, there is a library for just about everything...

Comment: I guess this link will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620498/comparing-two-times-with-moment-js

Comment: @VaishakHolla I did see that link but there it compares if it's before or after. I want to see what's the difference in hours between 2 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would map them into 24 hour time to start and loop over to see if number plus 2 and check for wrapping with a modulus.

```js
const textEveryTwo = data => {
  const hours = data.map(t => t === '12am' ? 0 : t === '12pm' ? 12 : (t.includes('pm') ? 12 : 0) + parseInt(t))
  return hours.every((h, i, a) => {
    var next = (h % 24 + 2) % 24
    return a[i + 1] === undefined || a[i + 1] === next
  })
}

console.log(textEveryTwo(['6pm', '8pm', '10pm', '12am', '2am', '4am', '6am', '8am', '10am', '12pm']))
console.log(textEveryTwo(['5pm', '7pm', '9pm', '11pm', '1am', '3am', '5am', '7am', '9am', '11am', '1pm']))
console.log(textEveryTwo(['5pm', '7pm', '10pm', '11pm', '1am', '3am', '5am', '7am', '9am', '11am', '1pm']))
```

Now it can be just with one loop, you would just have to transform the number each time.

```js
const textEveryTwo = data => {
  const getHours = t => t === '12am' ? 0 : t === '12pm' ? 12 : (t.includes('pm') ? 12 : 0) + parseInt(t)
  return data.every((h, i, a) => {
    var next = (getHours(h) % 24 + 2) % 24
    return a[i + 1] === undefined || getHours(a[i + 1]) === next
  })
}

console.log(textEveryTwo(['6pm', '8pm', '10pm', '12am', '2am', '4am', '6am', '8am', '10am', '12pm']))
console.log(textEveryTwo(['5pm', '7pm', '9pm', '11pm', '1am', '3am', '5am', '7am', '9am', '11am', '1pm']))
console.log(textEveryTwo(['5pm', '7pm', '10pm', '11pm', '1am', '3am', '5am', '7am', '9am', '11am', '1pm']))
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much you gain with a conversion to 24 hr format, if 11p->1a is an expected test case.

Comment: @WBT did you see the second test case?

Comment: I saw it was there, but am not sure how much gain the 24-hour system conversion provides. You have to do the modulo and flip the am/pm letter if the +2 value was >base pre-modulo, so changing to the 24-hour system doesn't really simplify things and does add a step of complexity.

Comment: Not sure how it complicates things. If you do not convert it than you are adding 2, if it goes over 12 then you have to subtract and see if the next has a am/pm. Either way it is the same thing.

Comment: @epascarello thanks, I did not think about it like that. Will probably need to study more on this

Comment: I added an answer to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are already using moment.js 
https://jsfiddle.net/y70foawq/
Check this jsfiddle

```js
let beginningTime = moment('8:45am', ["h:mm A"]);
let endTime = moment('9:00am', ["h:mm A"]);
let difference = moment.duration(endTime.diff(beginningTime));
let hours = difference.asHours();
console.log(hours)
```

You can work on top of this to check how many hour difference you need as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function for comparison.

```
function is2hDelayed(aHr, aDayHalf, bHr, bDayHalf) {
    if(aHr==12) {aHr = 0}
    if(bHr==12) {bHr = 0}
    return (aDayHalf == bDayHalf) ? (bHr == (aHr+2)) : ((bHr) == (aHr-10));
}
```

Example usage:   `is2hDelayed(11,"am",1,"pm")` should return `true`.

It requires you to do some parsing ahead of time to separate the numeric and letter portions of the time, but has benefits of being able to reused in a variety of settings (e.g. insensitive to "a" vs. "am" convention as long as it's consistent; can be used in a setting where minutes and seconds are given. etc.).

It also does not introduce extra complexity by converting to a 24-hour system, which only helps in the am->pm wrap without addressing pm->am.  The 12=>0 conversion is there because the "beginning" of a day half is indicated with 12 rather than 0.

Note that this function does not address daylight savings time and assumes a consistent time zone.  [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1883/).

Comment: So aHr and bHr are the hours we want to compare, what would aDayHalf and bDayHalf be then. And why did you need to do (aHr-10). Sorry just trying to understand more

Comment: @na2193 I added an example; does that help?  The `-10` is just simpler than `+2 mod 12`.

Comment: @epascarello Missed one, fixed it. Thanks.